Old Mortise Lockset - Help with latch
Could someone please let me know if the below latch (marked by red arrow) is a functional one or a decorative piece? I recently purchased this property and the latch does not work when I rotate the knob. Deadbolt works just fine. I am not certain if latch should work or not. I did not muster courage to open the lockset.
Any suggestions?


It is supposed to be functional. It has definitely not been maintained. Broken spring is very likely, accumulated crud and lack of lubrication is almost certain, other parts may be broken or worn out.
Speaking as a locksmith, I would dismount it, disassemble it, inspect it for wear, replace parts that have failed or look like they were going to fail soon, clean, lubricate, reassemble, and reinstall, testing as I go. If the lock mechanism turns out not to be reasonably repairable, I'd check the dimensions against catalogs and recommend a replacement.
Note that if you are going to change the key, this is the time to do so, since the lock cylinder has to be dismounted anyway in order to remove the lock mechanism from the door. I would apply the same principles there: disassemble and inspect, rekey and reassemble if it makes sense to do so, recommend a replacement if the existing cylinder is on its last legs.
Old mortise lock mechanisms are generally simple enough, and have large enough parts, that you might be able to replace springs, clean and lube it yourself. Of course if you do that wrong you may have trouble opening the door to remove the lock and try again, so if you are not especially handy I would recommend finding someone who does know what they're doing.
